# Custom Fields Unsorted

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have created custom fields that have specific positions. If I go into custom field sets in admin panel, they are correctly sorted. However, if I enter the product entities where they are displayed, they are no longer properly arranged. The SW version is 6.4.14.0

[product custom fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kwTn.png)

[custom fields set definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WqTN.png)

```
{"customFieldPosition":3,"label":{"de-DE":"Anzahl der Mahlzeiten 1","en-GB":"Number of meals 1","pl-PL":"Ilość posiłków 1"},"placeholder":{"de-DE":"Geben Sie die Anzahl der Mahlzeiten ein","en-GB":"Enter the number of meals","pl-PL":"Wprowadź ilość posiłków"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this got [fixed with version 6.4.15.0](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/9cfa721325a9cb71ed80115fda849121ae506552/changelog/release-6-4-15-0/2022-07-13-sort-custom-field-sorting-in-admin-view.md). [Here is](https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/7bbf61b10408555352eccde63d3e3968ab9cd147) the corresponding commit.

Comment: I checked that. It looks also good:
{"customFieldPosition":3,"label":{"de-DE":"Anzahl der Mahlzeiten 1","en-GB":"Number of meals 1","pl-PL":"Ilość posiłków 1"},"placeholder":{"de-DE":"Geben Sie die Anzahl der Mahlzeiten ein","en-GB":"Enter the number of meals","pl-PL":"Wprowadź ilość posiłków"}}

Comment: Turns out it was a more recent fix introduced with `6.4.15.0`. I updated my answer with the references.